# Etiqueta S:Select struts2 jdbc

Tags: java, web, jdbc, struts2

Hola estoy aprendiendo **Struts2**, estoy realizando un formulario de registro pero tengo una duda como puedo jalar los registros que se encuentran en una una tabla a la etiqueta `s:select` (prácticamente deseo hacer un *combobox* jalando datos de un campo de una tabla sql).

Esta es mi método de consulta a la *Base de Datos*:

```
private String sql6= "select distinct RazonSocial  from titular;";

    public List<Propietario> consultarPr()throws SQLException{ 
    List<Propietario> listadopr = new ArrayList<Propietario>();
    Connection con=Coneccion.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql6);
    ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();

    while(res.next()){
        Propietario p = new Propietario();
      p.setNombres(res.getString("RazonSocial"));

        listadopr.add(p);
    }
    ps.close();
    res.close();
    con.close();


    return listadopr;

}
```

Mi action:

```
private List<Propietario> listadopr = new ArrayList<Propietario>();
public String consultarPr() throws SQLException{
    ModelPropie ad = new ModelPropie();
    listadopr = ad.consultarPr();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Mi jsp :

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Titular</label>
                <s:iterator value="listadopr"> 
                <s:select class="form-control select2" name="p.UEA" style="width: 100%;" list="value" listvalue="RazonSocial" headerKey="">

                </s:select>
                </s:iterator>
              </div>
```

Donde dice name `p.UEA` es donde se registra el campo y lo guardo a la tabla de mi *Base de Datos*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tienes que usar un `s:iterator` en este caso. El tag [select](https://struts.apache.org/docs/select.html), en su atributo `list`, ya espera un iterable (map o list, normalmente). Entonces en tu caso deberías tener en tu action class un método como

```
  public Map<String,String> getListaRazonSocial() {
      Map<String,String> = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

      ... llenar el map
  }
```

(Es solo un ejemplo, y no tiene porqué ser `Map<String,String>`; podría ser un map de otros tipos, y también podría devolver una lista de objetos y usar listKey``  y `listValue` para decirle como extraer el key y el value de cada objeto).

El map devolvería como `key` el `value`que quedará en cada `option` del select, y el valor asociado corresponderá al texto que se muestra.

Y en tu jsp simplemente escribirias

```
  <s:select list="listaRazonSocial" name="p.UEA" style="..." />
```

Por supuesto que hay otras opciones, pero esta es la más sencilla